# Which Docker images will run on Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How can I find out if a given Docker image can be run using Kubernetes?

What should I do to help ensure that my images will run well in any Kubernetes-managed environment?

Comment: So far, I've heard the following: One process per container (for consistent health checks), and Container Images must match the target system architecture

Answer (score 2):

All Docker images can be run on Kubernetes -- it uses Docker to run the images.

You can expose ports from containers just like when using Docker directly, pass in environment variables, mount storage volumes from the host into the container, and more.

If you have anything particular in mind, I'd be interested in hearing about any image you find that can't be run using Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the **processor architecture** of the machine. If the image is compatible with the underlying hardware architecture, the K8s master node should be able to deploy the container. I had this problem when I try to deploy a Docker container on Raspberry pi 3(**ARM arch. machine**) with the Docker image which is built for x86-64.

For practical, try to deploy a container with the following image in X86-64 machine:

```
docker pull arifch2009/hello
```

The error will be shown :

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

This is a simple application to print "Hello World". However, the program/application inside the image is compiled in arm architecture. So, the binary file cannot be executed in other than ARM machine.